# Excel 2010 merge columns by inserting new rows

Tags: excel, vba, reorganize

I have a large csv file (about 10,000 rows) that I need to adapt to a new layout for the sake of uploading.

It is currently in a format like this:

```
Index1 Title1 1,2,3,4 Option1 A,B     OtherData
Index2 Title2 1,2,3   Option2 A,B,C,D OtherData
Index3 blank  blank   blank   blank   OtherData
Index4 Title4 1,2     blank   blank   OtherData
```

into something that looks like this.

```
Index1 Title1 1 Option1 A             OtherData
              2         B
              3
              4

Index2 Title2 1 Option2 A             OtherData
              2         B
              3         C
                        D

Index3                                OtherData

Index4 Title4 1                       OtherData
              2
```

I understand VBA only on a base level, and the columns are not necessarily A B C D, so if the macro could include comment lines to specify where the column is specified, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Better you try it first and comeback here when you get stuck ..

Comment: Lemme rephrase. I only know VBA on a "hello world" level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do something like what you need. Though I have made the assumption your file is Tab delimited.
It reads the file in using the FileSystemObject for which you'll need to add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime , go Tools > References and make sure it is checked. 
I've commented in where it is looking for specific column numbers but it should give you an idea of what to do.

```
Dim fs As New FileSystemObject
Dim ts As TextStream
i = 0
Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile("file.csv")
While Not ts.AtEndOfStream
    textline = Split(ts.ReadLine, Chr(9))
    Range("a1").Offset(i).Resize(1, 6).Value = textline  'Assumes there are six columns in the    file
    NewCol1 = Split(textline(2), ",")       'Split the 3rd word into an array (2 as it's zero based)
    NewCol2 = Split(textline(4), ",")       'Split the 5rd word into an array
    RowCount1 = UBound(NewCol1)
    RowCount2 = UBound(NewCol2)
    MaxCount = IIf(RowCount1 > RowCount2, RowCount1, RowCount2) 'Find the largest of the two row    counters as we need to move down this many rows
    If RowCount1 > 0 Then Range("a1").Offset(i, 2).Resize(RowCount1 + 1, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(NewCol1)  'Put the array vertically in the 3rd column
    If RowCount2 > 0 Then Range("a1").Offset(i, 4).Resize(RowCount2 + 1, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(NewCol2) 'Put the array vertically in the 5th column (4 along from cell    A1)
    i = i + MaxCount + 1
Wend
```

Comment: Got a bit confused until I ran it in a blank sheet. Then it worked like a charm. Thanks!